# Are open discs centered at some point $(x,0)\,\,,x\in\mathbb{R}$ form a basis for topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: general-topology

1. I actually have a doubt regarding this question which I found in one of my assignments. My thinking is that if the center $(a,0)$ is fixed then the collection of open discs should form a basis for topology as we can express the entire $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as the union of all sets from the basis.
   As well as the if we have a finite intersection of sets then it would be just the disc with the smallest radius which is itself a member of the basis. So by my logic this does form a basis if I am not completely wrong right?
2. But if the question means that the center is not fixed . Then we might have a problem because there could exist a point in the intersection of two circles which cannot be contained inside a circle which is centered on the x axis in  $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ .

The answer given was as "no" .
Then was any of my reasoning correct?. Is the collection of discs with fixed center not a basis for topology?.

Comment: What's the definition you currently have for a basis?

Comment: @Yorch If the union of all members of the basis is the set whole set , in this case $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ . And the finite intersection of the members of basis element is in the topological space generated by the basis. (The intersection can be expressed as some union of members of the basis open sets).

Comment: I don't think that definition is correct.

Comment: What kind of discs are you considering, those that are closed or those that are open in the standard topology? And are you asking if they constitute a basis for the standard topology or for some topology?

Comment: @md2perpe Open. I'll edit it in

Comment: @Yorch . It can be shown that if these conditions hold then the collection of sets is a basis for some topology on $X$. I am new to this. That's what the professor wrote as a theorem . That the union can be derived and the finite intersection of the members of topology can be expressed as a union of basis members. If you want I can provide the link.

Comment: That link would probably help people write an answer more useful to you.

Comment: @Yorch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txojxp_CuzA . at 21:18

Comment: There's no problem with touching discs if the discs are open. The touching point doesn't belong to the discs and is therefore not in the intersection (which is empty).

Comment: Oh ok :) but that condition isn't satisfied, for example look at the green area, it can't be made with disks like that https://imgur.com/a/BXiNaeM because in order to cover the green points near the top you need a large disk and it uses up points outside of the green area.

Comment: The Wikipedia on [bases in topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) gives the conditions for a set of subsets of a set to the base for a topology (and agrees with your comment). I agree with you that for fixed $x$, the set of open discs in $\Bbb{R}^2$ centred at $(x, 0)$ satisfies these conditions.  So I don't understand why the supplied answer is "no", unless $x$ is not fixed. It sounds like the problem you have been given has not been expressed very clearly.

Comment: @RobArthan but the x isn't fixed in the original problem.

Comment: @Yorch: the OP doesn't seem to be sure about that. And please note that the conditions for a base given in the OP's first comment are correct: see the Wikipedia link in my comment.

Comment: @md2perpe . Okay yeah I made that mistake. But if the center is not fixed then there will exist a point which cannot be contained inside a circle(centered at some point on x axis)which will not be contained in the intersection of both the circles right?.

Comment: yes :) although in the beginning I wasn't sure that OP wanted it to be a basis of "a space" instead of a already pre-specified space. @RobArthan

Comment: @Yorch: fair enough! To the OP: this is a good example of why it is good idea to make the body of your MSE questions self-contained: you have relied on the title to provide important information and I think this has misled people trying to help you.

Comment: @rob . Yeah I try to do so most of the times.  But this question itself was confusing me so much that I could nkt express it properly. I apologize for that. If you see my other posts I usually type as much info as I know or have gathered before I post the question.

Comment: OK. I appreciate that you were confused.

Comment: @yorch . Thanks for the image. That was the first thought that came to my mind but I wasn't sure how to write it. So I used the singleton intersection argument(which was totally wrong). To try and provide some concrete example for my argument. If you see some of my previous comments I have try to express what your image depicts in a vague sort of way. I'll try and prove it properly tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathscr{B} = \{D((a,0), r) : r > 0\}$. Then $\mathscr{B}$ is a base, but it is not the base for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To see that it's a base, we check that it covers $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that for any $B_1, B_2 \in \mathscr{B}$, there is a $B_3 \in \mathscr{B}$ with $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

For any $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let $r = d((x,y), (a,0))$. Then $D((a,0), r+1)$ is a basis element that contains $(x,y)$. So it covers $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $B_1 = D((a,0), r_1)$ and $B_2 = D((a,0), r_2)$ be two basis elements. Then $B_1 \cap B_2 = D((a,0), r')$ where $r' = \min(r_1, r_2)$. For any $(x,y) \in B_1 \cap B_2$, it will have distance less than $r'$ from $(a,0)$. Denote it $s$. Let $r_3 = \frac{r' + s}{2}$. Then $B_3 = D((a,0), r_3)$ will be a basis element containing $(x,y)$ and will be contained in the intersection.

This base does not generate the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example, consider the open disc of radius $1$ centered at $(0,2)$. You cannot write that open set as a union of basic open sets from your base.

To your edit: The answer is no, that this does not form a basis. Consider the discs centered at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ with radii $\frac{2}{3}$. Then there will be a point in the intersection that has distance further than $\frac{1}{3}$ from the $x$-axis. Therefore, you cannot have any disc inside their intersection that contains that point.

Comment: I get your answer. That is the logic I thought but I did not do it algebraically(it was a mcq question so I used intuition). But one of my questions was that what happens if the question meant the center can vary on the x-axis?. Then it should not form a basis right?. Because for some point in the intersection . There will not exist a circle centered on x axis containing that point and which is contained within the intersection right?. I'll upvote your answer regardless. But please answer this question for me. After that I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee So you're asking if, instead, we took the collection $\mathscr{B} = \{D((a,0), r) : a \in\mathbb{R}, r > 0\}$ instead of just fixing one $a$?

Comment: Yes. Actually I am not sure what the question means. So I have to consider both cases.  That is why I posted it  here  .

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee My answer has been edited.

Comment: captain. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee You're welcome!